# What the considerations to be taken when using and extending `errno` as default error handling pattern in user code?

Tags: linux, posix, errno

What considerations should be taken when using the Posix' `errno` error handling system in the user code?

- How to extend the existent error macros in the most portable way?
- Is it allowed to use the same error code naming: `E...` ?
- What are the considerations regarding thread safeness?
- Is there any other issue that is relevant when using `errno` as the default error handling pattern?

Comment: Does it make sense to return either a custom error or one of the predefined errors as appropriate?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sure! That's the idea.

Comment: The main consideration IMO is not to extend it at all. It's a flawed design that luckily could be fixed without too much damage to existing code by changing `errno` from an int to a macro, but there's no good reason to reuse it yourself, and it is possible that `errno` may not even be writable by user code.